# Difference in Stash, stop tracking in Source Tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Just wondering the difference between stop tracking and stash in GIT. I am using source tree as the tool. So is that possible to revert back when stash or stop tracking later point of time if needed.

What would be the best option if I want to hide the changes temporarily till I commit and pull the latest from remote and then add those changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash is the right way to go. You don't really want to stop tracking your files, right? You just want to temporarily put your changes aside, and then restore them - this is what Stash is designed to do.

For more information about `git stash`: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a guide or link where I can check the steps for this Stash function? Further can we do that for part of the code within a file as well?

Comment: Thanks, How about the second point that I have made in my comment?

Comment: Can we do stash for part of the code within a file as well?

Comment: If you make a modification in a file, and then run `git stash`, this will not stash the file, but it will restore the file to its state in the HEAD commit, and keep a copy the new state of this file in the stash.

Comment: In my case in source tree even after stash, I can see Uncommitted changes in the local branch. I would have thought after stash it just ignore those changes in the file and there is no need of committing. Not sure I am doing the right thing here. May be because this reason I am not able to merge local branch to local master

Comment: You have problems merging? Can you share what error you're getting?

Comment: No errors in the source tree, I can see "Uncommitted changes" at the top line of the local branch, The question is why all stashed files showing as Uncommitted.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that after `git stash` you still see uncommitted changes.
One way this can happen is if you are stashing changes in `.gitignore`. For example: Suppose you add a file called `1.txt` to your working directory, and then you add the line `1.txt` to `.gitignore`. Now, the uncommitted changes only include the change in `.gitignore`, and not the `1.txt`. After running `git stash`, this will stash changes in `.gitignore` and now you will see `1.txt` appearing again as uncommitted change.